# Visual Studio Source control explorer displays wrong folder names

Tags: visual-studio

My Source control explorer is displaying wrong random or empty names, i.e. in the folders area I see TFSServer > TeamProject > Branch > "Do not share t" while the source location textbox has the correct $/TFSServer/TeamProject/Branch/FolderName. I'm not sure if this is related to sharing the drop location folder on the build machine. Has anyone experienced something similar or know how to fix this?

This is happening both in Visual Studio 2005 and 2006 Team Edition.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be fixed after disabling the AVG link scanner.